# How to parse more than one tr tag in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

i am currently having problem parsing all the tr tags that occur in a table, i am able to parse the first tr tag but i am unable to understand how can i parse all the subsequent tr tags, i have thought of using a for loop but it didn't work.
i have included only partial code which includes the tr tags that i want to store in json file.

Here is what i tried:

```
def parseFacultyPage(br, facultyID):
    if br is None:
        return None

    br.open('https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_home.asp')
    response = br.open('https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/class_message_view.asp?sem=' + facultyID)
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    tables = soup.findAll('table')

    # Extracting basic information of the faculty
    infoTable = tables[0].findAll('tr')
    name = infoTable[2].findAll('td')[0].text
    if (len(name) is 0):
        return None
    subject = infoTable[2].findAll('td')[1].text
    msg = infoTable[2].findAll('td')[2].text
    sent = infoTable[2].findAll('td')[3].text
    emailmsg = 'Subject: New VIT Email' + msg
```

Here is the sample html code if the tr tag exists more than one.

```
<table width="79%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="350">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="1%" bgcolor=#FFFFFF>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="78%" bgcolor=#FFFFFF>



    <center><b><u>VIEW CLASS MESSAGE - Winter Semester 2015~16</u></b></center>
    <br><br>


        <br>
        <table cellpadding=4 cellspacing=2 border=0 bordercolor='black' width="100%">

        <tr bgcolor=#5A768D>
            <td width="25%"><font color=#FFFFFF>From</font></td>
            <td width="25%"><font color=#FFFFFF>Course</font></td>
            <td><font color=#FFFFFF>Message</font></td>
            <td width="10%"><font color=#FFFFFF>Posted On</font></td>
        </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#EDEADE" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#EDEADE'" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='#FFF9EA'">
                <td valign="top">RAGHAVAN R (SITE)</td>
                <td valign="top">ITE308 - Distributed Systems - TH</td>
                <td valign="top">Dear students,

As informed in the class, this is to remind you Today special class from 6 to 6.50 pm at same venue SJT 126.

regards

R. Raghavan
SITE</td>
                <td valign="top">11/02/2016 11:42:57</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#EDEADE" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#EDEADE'" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='#FFF9EA'">
                <td valign="top">SMART (APT) (ACAD)</td>
                <td valign="top">STS302 - Soft Skills - SS</td>
                <td valign="top">Dear Students,

As  04 Feb 16 to 08 Feb 16 were announced as “No Instruction days”, the first assessment that was supposed to happen from 08 Feb 16 to 12 Feb 16 is being postponed to 7th week (15 Feb 16 to 19 Feb 16)
</td>
                <td valign="top">10/02/2016 21:48:14</td>
            </tr>

        <tr bgcolor=#5A768D>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        </table>


    <br><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first iterate throw the rows like below and in each row, query the columns into the `columns` variable at the start

```
for index, row in enumerate(tables[1].findAll('tr')):
    if index==0:
        continue

    columns= row.findAll('td')
    name = columns[0].text
    if not name:
        return None
    subject = columns[1].text
    msg = columns[2].text
    sent = columns[3].text
```

EDIT: Looks like your html has two table structures. You need the inner one. So, use index 1 instead `tables[1]`

I've also added [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) around the iterator so you also have the row index. And using this, you can skip the header row, when `index==0`

Comment: your answer is right but i couldn't get it working for the html page i only included partial html code so your answer is not working for that and it is only storing message properly can you please look into the html code and tell me how to target it properly?

Comment: Please check if `tables[1]` gets you the inner table. Updated answer with some explanation

Comment: You mean `msg` is not taking any value in the third loop? Please be descriptive. You haven't mentioned how you're storing these values

Comment: i am sorry it is working i just passed return at the end so it only stored 1st message

Comment: and there is one more doubt, how can i check individual fields like all messages parsed with the data already there in the json file  after loading the json file?

Comment: You can try `json.load(f.read())` but you should probably check exisitng questions that already detail the answer